# Call a function when another finishes within a timer

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I have these two functions:

```
animation1();
animation2();
```

I want to execute animation2();  when animation1(); finishes on document ready, then every 10 seconds within:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
animation1();
animation2();   
    });
```

each animation has delays in them so might be tricky, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `animation1` and `animation2` return deferred objects, this can be done easily.

```
function animation1() {
    $(el).animate(...);
    return $(el).promise();
}
function animation2() {
    $(el).animate(...);
    return $(el).promise();
}
doAnimations() {
    animation1().done(animation2);
}
$(function(){
    doAnimations();
    setInterval(doAnimations,10*1000);
});
```